# Using Robocopy in Powershell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am having a challenge while trying to move a large number of files from one location to another. I have a list of folders that I want to move in a .csv and I want to move those items to a new network location. When I use robocopy, only the content of the folders is moved, not the top level folder. This leads to unorganized files. I have tried using move-item but there is not a good logging feature that I can get to work. So here I am.

I am trying to use robocopy but I need to create a destination folder based on the last part of the source path for each item in a list. I have been working on this for hours, please help.

```
GC -Path C:\Test_1\Test_List.csv | 
 ForEach-Object 
  {
   $Destination = new-item NAME BASED ON PART OF FILE -itemtype directory |
   Robocopy $_ $Destination /e /move /LOG+:C:\Test_2\Test_Copy_Log.txt /NP
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example source path and desired destination name?

Comment: If the file really is a CSV file, you want to use `Import-Csv` and not `Get-Content`. Also, you don't want to pipe data to the `robocopy` command (the line ending starting with `$Destination` should not end with `|`).

Comment: Source - \\Networkshare\A\1   Destination - \\DIfferentNetwrokShare\B\1 Essentiually I am trying to make up for Robocopy not copying my source folder and just taking the contnents. I would like to have the same source folder name (not the full path) at the destination.

Comment: Thank you Bill I will clean it up after finding a solution, I was just trying to show what I was looking for.